# How to check user permissions at SharePoint 2010 using Client Object Model?

Tags: sharepoint-2010

The following code always returns **false** (which is incorrect, as the user has Full Control permission at the site level):

```
Site site;
BasePermissions permissionMask;
ClientResult<bool> result;

permissionMask = new BasePermissions();
permissionMask.Set(PermissionKind.ManageWeb);
result = site.DoesUserHavePermissions(permissionMask);

return result.Value;
```

I am trying to utilize new SharePoint 2010 Client Object Model. I was thrilled when I discovered DoesUserHavePermissions method, but it appears that I'm not really sure if I know how to use it. I have no idea whether I am using the correct mask, or whether I should  specify the user account for which I wish to check the permissions level? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One important thing was missing - the Client Context. This object is responsible for the actual execution of the query over any SharePoint Client Object Model objects.

The code should be modified to the following:

```
ClientContext clientContext;
Site site;
BasePermissions permissionMask;
ClientResult<bool> result;

permissionMask = new BasePermissions();
permissionMask.Set(PermissionKind.ManageWeb);
//if we want to check ManageWeb permission
clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUri);
//siteUri is a method parameter passed as a string
clientContext.Credentials = credential;
//credential is a method parameter passed as a NetworkCredential object
//that is the user for which we are checking the ManageWeb permission
site = clientContext.Web;
result = site.DoesUserHavePermissions(permissionMask);

return result.Value;
```

This will return true if the user is assigned ManageWeb permissions, or false if otherwise. 
For a complete list of permissions enum, take a look at this [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spbasepermissions.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Just thought I'd add some code I'm using for this. Which is pretty much the same but without the bloat.

```
using (var context = new ClientContext(siteUrl))
{
   context.Load(context.Web);
   context.ExecuteQuery();
   BasePermissions permissionMask;
   ClientResult<bool> hasPermissions;
   permissionMask = new BasePermissions();
   permissionMask.Set(PermissionKind.ManageWeb);
   hasPermissions = context.Web.DoesUserHavePermissions(permissionMask);

}
```